# Details about ProGuard, Launch4j?

Tags: java, web-applications, struts2, proguard, launch4j

What is the purpose of ProGuard?

How to use Proguard in my web application project?

In web application project I used Struts 2.

How do use Launch 4j in my project for converting exe file. Before using Launch4j in my web application how to use ProGuard for hide the code?

Comment: Again, please don't bundle your complete application using launch4j: your client needs to be able to configure the web server on their own, or deploy it to their own server.

Comment: You should keep in mind that ProGuard may obfuscate code, but someone can still disassemble and reverse engineer what you are trying to hide. It will just be a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Its Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier details are very much available at project hosting site

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

here are the step by step details how to achieve this using launch4j

[Running launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

Comment: What are good windows InstallAnywhere replacements for installing a Java web application?

Comment: if you export it as .class file for java code will be no longer visible regarding your JSP you have not much choice

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am in need of convert my ERP based web application into single package. That contains eclipse,struts2 framework,jsp pages,java,Apache tomcat server,mysql database.client needs our ERP project as a single package.(by clicking the that Package that softwares required for ERP Project will install automatically and  i need code security of my project).Please suggest me.Thanks in advance.